# Google Docs scattering my uploaded content

Tags: google, google-drive

I've uploaded a folder which is full of other folders and files into Google Docs Webdav. After the upload was finished, I checked through the webdav and the website and everything was scattered. What is causing this? Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Scattered? What do you mean?

Comment: if i were to upload a folder called myfiles and inside this folder i had a folder called first and another folder called second. and in folder first i had a bunch of pdfs and in folder second i had a bunch of text files. so as of now i have the myfiles folder well organised. when i upload to google docs the folder structure is the same but the files in them are not inside anymore they are in the root directory. that is what happend to me but i have more folders than this example.

Answer (score 2):

When uploading folders, Google Docs creates collections. Per the Help Center, collections are a [mix of folders and labels](http://docs.google.com/support/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=68486&topic=15122). If you click on the collection of the same name as the folder you've uploaded, you should see a the same organization as the folder you've uploaded. However, [the default view of Google Docs](http://docs.google.com/support/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=1107581&topic=1084191) is 'Home,' which can be customized, but generally shows the most recently updated file.